# python connecting to Oracle using pyodbc sometimes kills python interpreter

Tags: python, oracle, pyodbc

Periodically when using pyodbc to create a connection to an oracle database, it kills the interpreter.

```
import pyodbc
connectString = 'Driver={Microdsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=<host>:<port>/<db>.<host>;uid=<username>;pwd=<password>'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connectString)
```

Say 1/5 of the time this will just drop me from the Python prompt (>>>) down to my dos prompt (C:)

Any ideas of why this happens or how to fix it?

Comment: "this will just drop me "  No message?  Really?  Have you tried running `top` or some other system monitor to see what's going on?  And this is the **only** code, with no query or anything else?  Can you provide a log that shows this happening, with all output that's produced?

Comment: @S.Lott I can recreate this problem with just the code above.  And yes, it just drops from the Python prompt to the DOS prompt.  It does not occur 100% of the time, maybe 25%, which makes it very hard to diagnose.  I am not sure of which log file to provide.  Is there a python.log file that I can review?

Comment: I have also seen a similar problem when performing an unzip using zipfile.ZipFile.extract on large zip files, though I have not written a test similar to above that I can easily replicate it.

Comment: @ccwhite1: "Is there a python.log file that I can review"?  There's stdout and stderr -- those are the output files from Python. It's almost impossible for Python to "just drops from the Python prompt to the DOS prompt" without showing an exception and a traceback on stderr.  Please provide the code and the output.

Comment: @S.Lott Thats what I thought, but that is exactly what happens.  Ill get you a screenshot

Comment: How do I post a SS in the comment?

Comment: @ccwhite1: Don't post **anything** in a comment.  This is **your** question.  **update** your question with **all** the information.

Comment: Cool, ill do that... if I can get it to re-occur, which currently I can't.  Last week I had it easily repeatable, now its just trying to make me look foolish.  If/When I get it, I will share it.

Comment: @ccwhite1: Include the Python version and the Windows version as well as the Oracle version information.

Comment: Python 2.7.1, Windows 2003 Server SP2, Oracle 10G

Comment: @ccwhite1: Don't post **anything** in a comment. This is your question. **update** your question with all the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could not discover what was exactly causing this problem.  Research leads us to think that there may be a problem with Python 2.7.1, PyODBC, and Win 2003 server.

To fix this problem we created a jar file that executed the permission check and then had the python script call that file and return the result